# Julia Juno: Implementation Error

Tags: atom-editor

I am trying to install Julia Juno in Atom
However, I got the following error.

> Juno: Error installing package ink
>
> Please check your internet connection, or report this to
>
> http://discuss.junolab.org
>
> and we'll try to help.
>
> –––
>
> Error: Installing “ink@0.10.10” failed.

Could anyone help me fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Report this to

http://discuss.junolab.org

and we'll try to help."

Comment: I don't know why I cann't reach the website "discuss.junolab.org" (I can go to junolab.org)

Comment: The correct link is https://discourse.julialang.org/